# Exporting GeoJSON data to gpx with togpx library in Leaflet?

Tags: leaflet, export, gpx

While doing research to assemble, cut tracks (polylines), I found a development called Leaflet.draw.plus: alas, abandoned : https://github.com/Dominique92/Leaflet.draw.plus .
I tried this leaflet.draw.plus.js API that matches the functions I was looking for.
My goal was to be able to export the processed data in geojson and gpx format with the togeojson.js and togpx.js APIs.

I succeeded in exporting to geojson, but not to gpx

Here is the code used in Plunker : https://plnkr.co/edit/dnfC4dA0r89a8mzg?open=lib%2Fscript.js&preview

The data to be exported are in the window: "geoJson input/output"

For the export to geojson I used the code

```
var geojson = document.getElementById('edit-json').value;
var donnees = '{"type":"FeatureCollection",' +geojson ;
var name = prompt('Enter file name','data'); // second param can be empty, it is the default value
document.getElementById('export').setAttribute('href', 'data:' + donnees);
document.getElementById('export').setAttribute('download', name + '.geojson');
}
```

For the export to gpx I tried (using this library https://github.com/tyrasd/togpx):

```
var geojson = document.getElementById('edit-json').value;
var gpx = togpx(geojson);
// Stringify the GeoJson
var convertedData = 'text/gpx;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent(gpx);
// Create export
var name = prompt('Enter file name','data'); // second param can be empty, it is the default value
document.getElementById('exportgpx').setAttribute('href', 'data:' + convertedData);
document.getElementById('exportgpx').setAttribute('download',name + '.gpx');
}
```

which does not work.
Which code should I use to realize this export ?

Answer (score 1):

You didn't describe what are you using for GPX export (so I edited your question with info about `togpx` library from https://github.com/tyrasd/togpx) and in what way it doesn't work, that upon export you get GPX file which has no points, just basic GPX framework.

You get an empty GPX file because you use string GeoJSON as input to `togpx`, but it should be parsed GeoJSON.

So your GPX create call should look like this:

```
var gpx = togpx(JSON.parse(geojson));
```